# JQuery scrollTop issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'll just jump to the problem.
I have some sections in my webpage, each has an id and I have a fixed Navbar which has links to those sections.
So I want to scroll to those sections and use offset so it doesn't overlap with my navbar.  I used this code:

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Well it works perfectly in chrome but it doesn't work neither in edge nor in chrome incognito. It kinda deactivates the links and they don't work. 
I've tested so many different solutions on this site and other sites, none of them solved the issue.
the only thing that was a kind of solution was this css code:

```css
:target::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 45px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin: -45px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

which is perfect but the only problem is I have this website on wordpress so there's this adminbar, and as I said I have a fixed navbar too so the offset value must change under some circumstances.
also I looked for changing that value with jquery but I faced another issue which was Selecting the css property. I couldn't find a way to select ':target::before' and change its property.
I really don't care about the animation. I just want this thing to work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to refer example below may help you to solve your issue.

The code is working fine with in MS Edge and also working fine in Chrome incognito mode.

Code leaves the proper amount of space between fixed navbar and other element on the page.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#tp").click(function(){

   var jump = $("#top").attr('href');

    var new_position = $(jump).offset();

 var n= new_position.top - 60;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: n}, 500);
 
 

  });
  
  $("#mdl").click(function(){

   var jump = $("#middle").attr('href');

    var new_position = $(jump).offset();
 var n= new_position.top - 60;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: n }, 500);
 


  });
  
  $("#btm").click(function(){

   var jump = $("#bottom").attr('href');

    var new_position = $(jump).offset();
 var n= new_position.top - 60;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: n }, 500);
 
 

  });
  
});
</script>
<style>
body {

padding-top:50px;

}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
a {
  background: orange;
  color: #444;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#star {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 500px;
  color: #ddd;
}
Resources
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="main">
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#1" id="tp">Top</a>
  <a href="#2" id="mdl">Middle</a>
  <a href="#3" id="btm">Bottom</a>
</div>

<a href="#top" id="top">Top element</a>

<div id="star">&star;</div>


<a href="#middle" id="middle">Middle element</a>

<div id="star">&star;</div>


<a href="#bottom" id="bottom">Bottom element</a>

<div id="star">&star;</div>

<div id="star">&star;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge browser:

[image]

Output in Chrome incognito mode:

[image]